# como puedo eliminar elementos especificos de una listbox en tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, botón, listbox

COMO PUEDO HACER PARA ELIMINAR UN ELEMENTO EN ESPECIFICO DE UNA LISTBOX EN PYTHON TKINTER , ESTO LO QUIERO HACER AL PRESIONAR ESE ELEMENTO.COMO HAGO PARA QUE SUCEDA ESO.

NOTA:TENGO UN BOTON PARA PODER ELIMINAR , PERO LO QUE ME FALTA ES AGREGARLE LA FUNCION QUE NO SE COMO HACER PARA HACER LO ANTERIOR.

Comment: Dos cosas. Primero, por favor evita usar mayúsculas, da la impresión de que estás gritando. Segundo, podrías agregar la etiqueta Python por favor? Pues tu pregunta, además de ser de Tkinter, es de Python.

Comment: Otra cosa, yo cambiaría el titulo a uno que explique tu problema con más detalle. Por ejemplo "Eliminar elemento seleccionado Listbox Tkinter".

Comment: @DanteS.  , mmm soy nuevo en esta plataforma ,la verdad , soy nuevo en la programacion en general , y me encanto el tema,y  si, claro dejare de usar las mayusculas , y gracias por todos los 'consejos ' o sugerencias , las tomare en cuenta , y no sabia que poner como titulo , pero tratare de mejorar eso , muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada, te recomiendo esta pagina para aprender más del widget listbox de tkinter: https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/lista-listbox-en-tkinter/

Sin embargo, explicaré más abajo los comandos que vamos a usar en nuestra solución.

#### listbox.delete(desde, hasta)

Para borrar un elemento de un listbox, puedes usar el método delete.

```
listbox.delete(desde, hasta)
```

Donde `desde` es desde que posición eliminar y `hasta` es hasta que posición borrar. Por ejemplo si tenemos un `listbox` con los items ("Python", "C++", "Java", "Lua"), el comando `listbox.delete(0, 2)` borraría desde la posición `0` (Python) hasta la posición `2` incluida ("Java").

Este método también acepta esta sintaxis.

```
listbox.delete(item)
```

Donde `item` es la posición del item a eliminar.

#### listbox.curselection()

Este método se usa para obtener una tupla con la posición de los elementos seleccionados. No acepta ningún argumento.

#### Solución

Como podrás haber notado, los dos métodos antes mencionados nos podrían servir para nuestro propósito.
Si asumimos que el usuario solo puede seleccionar un elemento del *listbox*, este código de ejemplo debería de servir.

```
from tkinter import *

listbox = Listbox()
listbox.insert(0, "Python", "C++", "Java")
listbox.pack()

def borrar_seleccion():
    # obtenemos la posición del primer item seleccionado
    item = listbox.curselection()[0]

    # eliminamos dicho elemento con el método delete.
    listbox.delete(item)
    
    

b = Button(command=borrar_seleccion)
b.pack()
```

Comment: un poco confusa la redundancia de palabras *desde* y *hasta*

Comment: GRACIAS , YA VOY A PROBAR CON ESE EJEMPLO COMO ME SALE LO QUE ESTOY HACIENDO , MUCHAS GRACIAS...SALU2

Comment: @JULIOVIEIRA_DO Si mi respuesta te sirvió, puedes apoyarme [aceptandola](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Un placer ayudarte, saludos c: